# Reverse debug using gdb on linux x86-64

Tags: linux, gdb, reverse-debugging

I wanted to try out reverse-step and other reverse commands. I compiled the program below with `gcc -g main.c`. I ran gdb and did the following and got the following

```
(gdb) record
Process record: the program is not being run.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1148: file main.c, line 3.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe7b8) at main.c:3
3       puts("Hello");
(gdb) record
(gdb) br 6
Breakpoint 2 at 0x555555555175: file main.c, line 6.
(gdb) step
Process record does not support instruction 0xc5 at address 0x7ffff7f1dfc9.
Process record: failed to record execution log.

Program stopped.
0x00007ffff7f1dfc9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

What's wrong? Without record I'd get the error `multi-thread does not support this command.`. Is there another command I need? Or a way to build/run this as a single thread?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    puts("Hello");
    puts("a");
    puts("b");
    puts("c");
    puts("d");
    puts("Hello 2");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://rr-project.org/ -- chances are it fits your needs better than GDB `record`.

Comment: GDB's reverse debugging lacks support for many modern x86-64 instructions.  If your program execution hits any of these unknown instructions then GDB doesn't know what the instruction does, and so does not know how to "record" the instruction so it can be undone later.  I'd also suggest checking out `rr`.